# Changing/Removing Flash Builder swc build path when showing errors

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, swc

I've done some searching on this issue, but I haven't gotten any solid answers. The closest I got was a question asked here: [How to use a relative path for a swc library in Flash Builder 4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612072/how-to-use-a-relative-path-for-a-swc-library-in-flash-builder-4-6) however this isn't exactly what I want.

When an error is thrown in my project, I can see the full path of my .swc file in the flash debugger.

```
    TypeError: Error #1085: The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>". at utility::utilController/receiveData()[/Users/myUserName/Documents/Public/packages/DataController/src/data/MainData.as:256]
```

To explain further, what happens is, an XML file is loaded and parsed.  Sometimes there is an error with the XML file being loaded and even though i have an IO_ErrorEvent handler, the error mentioned above will still come up in the debugger at run time.  I'm just trying to figure out a way to hide the path to my MainData.as file when that does happen.  So instead of seeing

```
TypeError: Error #1085: The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>". at utility::utilController/receiveData()[/Users/myUserName/Documents/Public/packages/DataController/src/data/MainData.as:256]
```

you would see something like:

```
TypeError: Error #1085: The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>". at utility::utilController/receiveData()[../data/MainData.as:256]
```

So that my complete path to my .as file doesn't appear.  Hopefully that clears up my question.

Comment: It's really unclear what is your question. Are you making your custom library? Are you trying to add a SWC file to your project? Please describe your problem in more details.

Comment: I say run full build after changing path, should do.

Comment: Also, that looks like you dropped out the most important part of the error (the beginning). What's the error number?

Comment: I've re-structured my question.  In the heat of the moment it seemed like it made sense but after looking at it a few days later, i realized i wasn't very clear at all.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just doing a release build.  I was going to have to do this inevitably anyway so this solved my problem.